# Cancel order on Amazon by using Amazon Marketplace Web Service

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, amazon-mws

I am using this code to ship my order on Amazon. This xml request is sent to the Amazon Marketplace Web Service, and my order gets shipped. Now I want to cancel the order using the same Web Service. But I am not sure what changes I have to make to the xml to perform the order cancel process. Can anyone help?

```
<cfsavecontent variable="Final_FulFillMent_XML">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <AmazonEnvelope xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

        <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>xxxxxxxxxxxx</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>

    <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OrderFulfillment>
        <AmazonOrderID>#AmazonOrderID#</AmazonOrderID>
        <MerchantFulfillmentID>#MerchantFulfillmentID#</MerchantFulfillmentID>
        <FulfillmentDate>#FulfillmentDate#</FulfillmentDate>
        <FulfillmentData><CarrierCode>#CarrierCode#</CarrierCode>
        <ShippingMethod>#ShippingMethod#</ShippingMethod>
        <ShipperTrackingNumber>#ShippingTrackingNumber#</ShipperTrackingNumber>
        </FulfillmentData></OrderFulfillment>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfhttp method="post" url="#FinalQueryString#">
    <cfhttpparam name="Content-Type" type="header" value="text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1">
   <cfhttpparam name="FeedContent" type="body" value="#Final_FulFillMent_XML#">
   <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-MD5" value="#ToBase64(BinaryDecode(Hash(Final_FulFillMent_XML), 'hex'))#">       
</cfhttp>
```

Answer (score 1):

To cancel **entire orders**, you need to modify the an "Order Acknowledge Feed" that you're probably sending already and specify a `StatusCode` of `Failure` and a `CancelReason`, e.g. `BuyerCanceled`.

To cancel **partial orders**, you need to send an "Order Adjustment Feed" which lets you specify how many items you were unable to ship and why.

Both XML feeds are described in [Selling on Amazon: Guide to XML](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I do have looked into the guide, and i have also found the Order Acknowledge Feed xml format but xml format feed required 'MerchantOrderID' and i have not idea how to find this id, can you help me on this.

Comment: @OmerAnees MerchantOrderIDs are a way to associate an amazon order (somthing like 123-1234567-1234567) with your own order number (e.g. 54321), if you have such a thing. If you provide it to Amazon, you will be able to see your own order number in Seller Central, and subsequent xml feeds can then either reference the Amazon order id or your own.

Comment: According to Amazon guide i am using Order Acknowledge Feed to cancel the order but it gives an error that is: 'The XML you submitted is ill-formed at the Amazon Envelope XML level at (or near) line 1, column 485'.

@Hazzit i post an other question about the xml format issue can you please help me about this?

Amazon Order Acknowledgment feed:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254327/amazon-order-acknowledgment-feed

Comment: feed name: _POST_ORDER_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_DATA_