# Amazon Order Acknowledgment feed

Tags: amazon-mws

I am using the Order Acknowledgment feed to cancel the order for Amazon. Below is the xml feed format that I am using to cancel the Amazon order.

I have successfully been able to submit this feed to MWS, but every time when I check the feed submission result it always gives this error

> 'The XML you submitted is ill-formed at the Amazon Envelope XML level
>   at (or near) line 1, column 485'.

I created the xml format according to this [Selling on Amazon: Guide to XML](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl.pdf).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">

<Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>M_xxxxxx_108291953</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>

<MessageType>OrderAcknowledgment</MessageType>
<Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OrderAcknowledgement>
        <AmazonOrderID>123-1234567-1234567</AmazonOrderID>
        <StatusCode>Failure</StatusCode>
        <CancelReason>BuyerCanceled</CancelReason>
    </OrderAcknowledgment>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Can any one help me what i am missing here in the xml format?

Answer (score 6):

There are two problems with your XML code:

1. Amazon uses "OrderAcknowledgement", not "OrderAcknowledgment". While that choice may be [debatable](http://grammarist.com/spelling/acknowledgment-acknowledgement/), the XSDs do not leave any room for a different spelling. (this applies to the `MessageType` and both opening and closing XML tag, your spelling is correct for the opening tag only)
2. `CancelReason` is only valid inside `<Item>` substructures.

The following XML validates:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>M_xxxxxx_108291953</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>OrderAcknowledgement</MessageType>
<Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OrderAcknowledgement>
        <AmazonOrderID>123-1234567-1234567</AmazonOrderID>
        <StatusCode>Failure</StatusCode>
        <Item>
            <AmazonOrderItemCode>12345678901234</AmazonOrderItemCode>
            <CancelReason>BuyerCanceled</CancelReason>
        </Item>
        <Item>          
            <AmazonOrderItemCode>12345678901235</AmazonOrderItemCode>
            <CancelReason>BuyerCanceled</CancelReason>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <AmazonOrderItemCode>12345678901237</AmazonOrderItemCode>
            <CancelReason>BuyerCanceled</CancelReason>
        </Item>
    </OrderAcknowledgement>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Comment: I tried with same xml that you have posted here, i used one item for the order to cancel. but i am getting same error. any idea what else i am missing?

Comment: Because of my bad formatting, the closing AmazonEnvelope tag was not visible in my post, sorry. I just corrected that, and have checked above source to insure what you see here is actually valid. Please try again.

Comment: Finally the error is removed, but now it says this: 'We are unable to process the XML feed because one or more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed' @Hazzit you have any idea about this?

Comment: No, not really. Check the AmazonOrderItemCodes and AmazonOrderID, see if they actually match the order you're trying to cancel.

Comment: I make sure that i am using the correct amazon order and item id, i also tried with the new order id but it also didn't worked too. it still saying invalid item. I don't know what to do now, I am wondering did any one ever done the successful amazon order cancellation?

@Hazzit can you please have a look on this, thanks:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342768/amazon-mws-order-cancel-process