# Amazon mws - Update MerchantOrderID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I'm trying to update the Amazon Merchant Order ID through the Feed API.

It was succesfully submitted and I've checked the response from Amazon MWS Scratchpad by check with the GetFeedSubmissionResult call. it returned that the process was completed without any erro.

But when I open my order in Amazon (sellercentral.amazon.com) it says "none saved": Your Merchant Order ID: # none saved

Nothing have been changed.

Comment: please provide a sample XML you're sending through SubmitFeed

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>M_xxxxx_114513393</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>OrderAcknowledgement</MessageType>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OrderAcknowledgement>
      <AmazonOrderID>114-8862878-1197857</AmazonOrderID>
      <MerchantOrderID>abc-402637</MerchantOrderID>
      <StatusCode>Success</StatusCode>
    </OrderAcknowledgement>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>

Comment: Hi Hazzit, above is the sample XML i used. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your XML feed (provided in your comment) is missing the `<Item>` elements. Amazon wants you to acknowledge that you have not only received the order, but also all contained items. A complete XML feed should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>M_xxxxx_114513393</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>OrderAcknowledgement</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OrderAcknowledgement>
            <AmazonOrderID>114-8862878-1197857</AmazonOrderID>
            <MerchantOrderID>abc-402637</MerchantOrderID>
            <StatusCode>Success</StatusCode>
            <Item> <-- you need to repeat the "Item" element for each order line
                <AmazonOrderItemCode>abc</AmazonOrderItemCode>
                <MerchantOrderItemID>def</MerchantOrderItemID> <-- I'm not sure this is required, but haven't tried without
            </Item>
        </OrderAcknowledgement>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

( the `<-- ...` comments are not part of the actual feed)

You may also wish to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18281256/2097290) related StackOverflow answer.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I will try to include the <Item> elements back and test again. But it's strange that in Amazon Scratchpad, I've tried the same XML and it's able to reflected the change. Anyway, thanks for that answer!!!